# Joda-Time library is not working in EJB

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jodatime

i am trying to use joda-time-2.5 in stateless ejb3.0 by adding joda-time-2.5.jar in class path. But it throwing

> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadablePartial.

For testing i created a Stand-Alone Java Application, there it is working fine.

Calling statement in EJB:

```
long days=DateCalculationsWithJoda.daysBetweenUsingJoda(date1,date2);
```

My Class for Date calculations:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class DateCalculationsWithJoda {

    public static long daysBetweenUsingJoda(Date d1, Date d2) { 
        long days=0;
        System.out.println("in side daysBetweenUsingJoda()");
        try {
            days= Days.daysBetween( new LocalDate(d1.getTime()), new LocalDate(d2.getTime())).getDays(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return days;
    } 
}
```

Stack trace:

```
00:58:47,568 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component AdmissionBean for method public abstract java.util.Hashtable org.cyfd.sara.ejb.session.AdmissionRemote.displayPopulationReport(java.util.Hashtable): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadablePartial
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:217) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.supports(CMTTxInterceptor.java:363) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:194) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:179) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:179) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
at $Proxy51.displayPopulationReport(Unknown Source) at org.cyfd.sara.war.managed.reports.AdmissionReleaseReportManagedBean.displayReport(AdmissionReleaseReportManagedBean.java:1076)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:68)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.cyfd.sara.war.utility.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadablePartial
... 73 more
```

Control is not going in `daysBetweenUsingJoda()` as it was not printed on screen.

Comment: Well it sounds like you haven't got Joda Time in your classpath properly. Where have you put the jar file, in your deployment?

Comment: i put it in WEB-INF/lib and i added it to build path tool in eclipse in EJB module.

Comment: Did you packaged your application as war or ear? where did you put your library in your deployment package? can you open  your war/ear file and see whether your joda jar file exist in the lib folder or not?

Comment: it is packaged as EAR and i opened it and found joda jar was there in EJB module @ Project\Project9EJB\lib

Comment: Which server you are using? JBoss? which version?

Comment: server-jboss-as-7.1.1

Comment: Is there an entry is the Manifest file?

Comment: i opened MANIFEST.MF
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Class-Path:

Comment: Are you using any building tool such as Gradle or Maven? If so, could you please update your question with the build dependencies' file(s)?

Comment: no i am not using any building tool. just using eclipse indigo for development.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved it by making Date related calculation with Joda-time on Managed beans rather than EJB. In EJB module it's not working. i don't know reason right now, but will update it.

second alternative solution to calculate days in between two dates, In EJB we can use following code rather than using Joda-time:

```
public static int daysBetween(Calendar day1, Calendar day2){
Calendar dayOne = (Calendar) day1.clone(),
        dayTwo = (Calendar) day2.clone();

if (dayOne.get(Calendar.YEAR) == dayTwo.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
    return Math.abs(dayOne.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - dayTwo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
} else {
    if (dayTwo.get(Calendar.YEAR) > dayOne.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        //swap them
        Calendar temp = dayOne;
        dayOne = dayTwo;
        dayTwo = temp;
    }
    int extraDays = 0;

    int dayOneOriginalYearDays = dayOne.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    while (dayOne.get(Calendar.YEAR) > dayTwo.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        dayOne.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        // getActualMaximum() important for leap years
        extraDays += dayOne.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    }

    return extraDays - dayTwo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + dayOneOriginalYearDays ;
}
}
```

This code i am using because i don't want to use getTime() of java.util.date.
getTime() will work 99% of the time, but especially if you are using java 6 or java 7 then, getTime() will not handle any special cases e.g. time or timezone, leap years, or day light saving time. It will fail on summer boundaries when day light changes occur. so it may give unexpected O/P.